# Broadcast Reciever, ¿Am I doing it right?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-toast

first question here...
I have this practice from my college, but the course sometimes doesn't explain everything, and it's about broadcast and receiving a Toast message.

(Some things are going to be in Spanish)

You see, the first app it's about having a view with a button:
[Activity View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GBlS.png)

The only thing that it does is sending a message through a button, and the OnClick has linked this method that is on the Activity, which name is *Emisora.java* (there is no main activity, but it is configured to this be the launch activity):

```
public void Emision(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.tecmilenio.practica91");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

The Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tecmilenio.practica91">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Emisora">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then I have the other app, which doesn't have an activity but it does have an Broadcast Reciever:

```
package com.tecmilenio.receptor;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadcastReceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Transmission Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

(I know having a Toast for this is not the best practice but is just for the practice of the course)

And its Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tecmilenio.receptor">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceptor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tecmilenio.practica91"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And when I install and execute the first one it just doesn't happen anything, I tap the button but nothing happens.

Then I later saw that in the second project (the receiver) when I execute it from the Android Studio, the app doesn't appear in the phone, neither execute anything, but i thought this was normal due to the lack of an activity in it. Then I also saw that when executing through the studio also the Run console sends me the message *"Timed out waiting for process (com.tecmilenio.receptor) to appear on xiaomi-mi_8-2ef63c6e."*, maybe this has something to be (?)

I would appreciate that someone explains me this... Thanks!

**Update**

I have found that the problem has to be a lot with the Timeout on launch, adding an activity with nothing and launching that activity makes it work, however that is not what it's supposed to do, it is supposed that it shouldn't have any activity, and should execute the OnRecieve when the "practica91" app sends the message...
Is there any way of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set action declared in manifest and sending broadcast from an activity is different.

try using the same action at both the places -

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.tecmilenio.practica91");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I didn't understood pretty well, I already wrote that code, or, what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small mistake here. You're sending as an action in the first app 
the following string **`com.tecmilenio.emision`**. Whereas in the second app you're registering the broadcast's action as below

```
<action android:name="com.tecmilenio.practica91"/>
```

The first change would be to rename the broadcast action to  **`com.tecmilenio.emision`**.

```
   <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceptor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tecmilenio.emision"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Another important point is that when sending the broadcast add `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` flag to the intent because when you broadcast from app A to app B , app B might not be running, this flag insures that the broadcast reaches out even apps not running:

Regards I'm Mexican too!

Comment: Well, fun fact, the app A which is the one making the emission is called Practica 9.1, so the package is com.tecmilenio.practica91, and the app B is called Receptor, which package is com.tecmilenio.receptor...
It didn't work even when i did another proyect named Emisor, however it does execute a System.out if I insert it in the method Emision, so the app does work, whit it doesn't, I think, is the Receptor app...

¡Saludos amigo, gracias!